How to scale an image on hover without messing with other elements, while also respecting max-width, using only CSS?
I'm trying to add zoom on hover to some images. The entire images should be viewable while zoomed in.
First I tried classic scale transformation, but it doesn't work well with smaller devices like mobile as the scaled images exceed the viewport width:


.scaled {
  max-width: min(350px, 95%);
}

.scaled:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: scale(3);
  transition-delay: .5s;
}
 
.main {
  display: flex;
}
 
.main div {
  flex: 1;
}
  <div class="main">
    <div>
      <p>Some other stuff that shouldn't be relocated, the 50/50 flex should be preserved</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/900" class="scaled" />
    </div>
  </div>



Adding max-width to :hover here does nothing as it's ignored by transform.
This max-width transition method, on the other hand, messes up the flex layout on desktop devices:


.scaled {
  max-width: min(350px, 95%);
}

.scaled:hover {
  max-width: 85vw;
  transition: max-width .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}
 
.main {
  display: flex;
}
 
.main div {
  flex: 1;
}
  <div class="main">
    <div>
      <p>Some other stuff that shouldn't be relocated, the 50/50 flex should be preserved</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/900" class="scaled" />
    </div>
  </div>



And if you set max-width to e.g. 95% instead, it doesn't really zoom in.
Is there any way to keep the "don't affect anything else in the DOM" property of transform, but also restrict the maximum width of the transformation scale? While using only CSS.

Any actual size change will affect standard layout. A proper scale would be the optimal solution. Frankly on mobile people will zoom in if they want to see better so perhaps you could disable the scale at that size. Alternatively, just reduce the scale to a smaller value in a media query.

Why not scale the image but put overflow: hidden on the containing div? It's not exactly the same effect but it's a functional replacement.

https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oNrXONY

Thanks for your comments. overflow is not desired, the whole image should be viewable as in both examples. Lower/disabled scale with media queries is an option, not too dynamic one in itself though, I would need to cover bunch of different resolutions with perfect scaling for them. I think I'll just go with some JS library adapted for this in the end if there's nothing better with just CSS at this moment.

Fair enough, only thing I can think of is to have the max-width at say 1/3 then go to 100% on hover - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ExBjJgK?editors=1100 Again, not precisely what you are after but a reasonable alternative (sans library). ☺

What would the ideal behavior be that you're looking for? I understand the general idea of what you want to happen, but I'm not sure precisely what you would want the final result to be.

Scaling an image with width limit and without affecting position/width of other elements.

I would recommend just not bothering with mobile functionality for this one. You cannot hover on touch devices anyway and a lightbox would serve the same functional purpose without any of the hassle.
